# First Passage time of random walk on reals

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, stochastic-integrals

If i have a random walk with $x(i+1)=x(i)+\cos(\theta_i)$ starting at $x(0)=0$ where $\theta_i \sim U[0,2\pi]$, then what would the distribution of my first passage time be? Specifically if I have $x(t)=Z $ what is the distribution of this $t$ for a fixed $Z\in \mathbb{R}$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is a new uniform RV used for each step? Since otherwise, as written you have $x(0)=0$, $x(1)=0+\cos \theta$, $x(2)=2\cos(\theta)$, so in general $x(n)=n\cos(\theta)$ for any $n\geq 0$. The walk will only be in one direction since only one step value is ever used. So, e.g. if $\cos(\theta)<0$ the first passage time of any $Z>0$ never occurs, i.e. is infinite. This happens with non zero probability for $\theta \sim \mathcal{U}(0,2\pi)$. Is this the behavior you had in mind? Or did you mean to study $x(i+1)=x(i)+\cos(\theta_i)$ where $\theta_1,\theta_2,\dotsc$ are IID uniform RVs?

Comment: It would be the latter, I would like to study  $x(i+1)=x(i)+\cos(\theta_i)$ where $\theta_1,\theta_2,\dotsc$ are IID uniform RVs?